# Select a <select> <option> based on it's value containing a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

```
<select id='mySelect'>
<option value='FirstOption'>
Option 1
</option>
<option value='SecondOption'>
Option 2
</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to select the 2nd option based on the fact it has the word 'Second' in it's name.

**What I've Tried**

```
$('#mySelect').val('SecondOption');
```

Closest I've got. Obviously returns second option, but wouldn't work for 'AnotherSecondOption'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [* attribute-contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('#mySelect option[value*="Second"]').prop('selected',true);
```